# Как проверить файл на Китайский текст

Tags: c#

У меня есть файл `test.txt` в котором присутствует текст: `㐨�ᵪ勿魉➈䚂ｨ聂⑽₅硪▒地䰗倓쾄绻唔઩㯔옅꼴塟䂕蓘篛i`
Мне нужно проверить если в файле начало строки начинается не с Русских букв или Английских и конец, то вернуть `false`, если  присутствует то `true`
Проверку делаю так, но как правильно реализовать?

```
public static bool CheckChina()
{
  string fullfilepath = Path.Combine(desktopath, "11.txt");
  if (!fullfilepath.Contains("䚂ｨ")) // Текст Китайский разный ( может не совпадать )
  {
     return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Начнём с того, что в китайском языке сам чёрт ногу сломит. Его символы не расположены в одном диапазоне.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1366113/5045688

Соответственно, проверять нужно во всех этих диапазонах.

Более того, код одного из символов, которые вы привели в вопросе - `䚂` - равен FF68. И он, насколько я могу судить, не входит ни в один из этих диапазонов. В то же время google translator определяет его как китайский. В общем, разбирайтесь сами.

---

Вот так можно сделать проверку по нескольким диапазонам. Тут несколько проходов по строке, но оставлю так ради понятности.

```
public static bool ContainsChinese(string text)
{
    return
        text.Any(c => c >= '\u4E00' && c <= '\u9FFF') ||
        text.Any(c => c >= '\u3400' && c <= '\u4DBF') ||
        text.Any(c => c >= '\uF900' && c <= '\uFAFF');
}
```

Есть диапазоны, которые в кодировке UTF-16 (это внутреннее представление строк в .NET) будут состоять из суррогатных пар. Например, 20000-215FF. Для работы с ними, видимо придётся использовать класс [StringInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.stringinfo).

```
Console.WriteLine(ContainsChinese("㐨�ᵪ勿魉➈䚂ｨ聂⑽₅硪▒地䰗倓쾄绻唔઩㯔옅꼴塟䂕蓘篛i"));  //True
```

---

Другой вариант - используем регулярки.

[Supported named blocks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#supported-named-blocks) - здесь перечислены именованные блоки, которые можно использовать в регулярных выражениях. Например, так:

```
private static readonly Regex cjkRegex = new Regex(
    @"\p{IsCJKUnifiedIdeographs}|\p{IsCJKCompatibilityIdeographs}|\p{IsCJKCompatibilityForms}",
    RegexOptions.Compiled);

public static bool ContainsChinese(string text)
{
    return cjkRegex.IsMatch(text);
}
```

В шаблоне я указал три блока. Перечисляются они через знак `|`. По идее, туда нужно добавить все, содержащие в названии CJK. Выберите нужные вам диапазоны.

```
Console.WriteLine(ContainsChinese("㐨�ᵪ勿魉➈䚂ｨ聂⑽₅硪▒地䰗倓쾄绻唔઩㯔옅꼴塟䂕蓘篛i"));  //True
```

Answer (score 2):

Указать диапазон(ы) и сверять символы по ASCII.

```
public static bool CheckChina()
{
  string fullfilepath = Path.Combine(desktopath, "11.txt");
  foreach(char c in fullfilepath)
    for (int i = 19966; i < 21007; ++i)
       (int)c == i ? return true : continue;
return false;
} // Возможно не работает, давно не писал на шарпах
```

https://unicode-table.com/ru/blocks/cjk-unified-ideographs/